# After the first reload: "nginx: [error] open() "/var/run/nginx.pid" failed (2: No such file or directory)"

Tags: nginx, pid, salt-stack

Using Salt I applied states that install and run NGINX (1.14.0-0ubuntu1.7) as a service. Service's status is active but `systemctl reload nginx` keeps failing thus an updated config cannot be applied.

Full logs:

```
systemd[1]: nginx.service: Can't open PID file /run/nginx.pid (yet?) after reload: No such file or directory
systemd[1]: Reloaded A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
systemd[1]: Reloading A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
nginx[18095]: nginx: [error] open() "/var/run/nginx.pid" failed (2: No such file or directory)
systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
systemd[1]: Reload failed for A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
systemd[1]: Reloading A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
nginx[1209]: nginx: [error] invalid PID number "" in "/var/run/nginx.pid"
systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
systemd[1]: Reload failed for A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

Comment: What is location for PID file in Nginx configuration? In your logs it shows two `/run/` and `/var/run/`. Make sure that `user` defined in conf file has the permission to create the `.pid` file.

Comment: @seshadri_c `/var/run/nginx.pid` is a pid file from `nginx.conf` but the default nginx service unit operates this command: `ExecStop=/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5 --pidfile /run/nginx.pid`. (`ExecReload=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; -s reload`) I suppose that `/run/nginx.pid` is a default fallback.

`root` user both starts and reloads the service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the main problem in this case is the fact that the NGINX service had been started initially before the needed `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` was placed. In my opinion, this order causes NGINX searches the PID file defined in the nginx.conf but the PID location policy was different during the start thus the PID file was not defined in the place expected by the reloading service.

However, service.running watches `file: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`. But it is not enough because the first start of the service occurs just after the package installation with the default `nginx.conf`.

To sum up, the solution is to place `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` with different `pid` directive before the package installation (if the package is installed ensure that all NGINX processes are killed, start the service with the needed `nginx.conf` OR [be careful, backup configs...] just fully remove the package disabling services and removing configs). In case of Salt Stack put `- require_in: pkg: nginx` (`nginx` here is the name of the package installation state) into the state that manages the `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by **restarting** nginx instead of **reloading**:

```
service nginx restart
service nginx status
```

after this, also a reload worked fine and the pid number is stored in

```
 /var/run/nginx.pid
```